# Is it safe to plug a power USB C hub on Desktop PC?

Tags: power-supply, power, usb-c, usb-hub

My situation is, if I have a USB C hub which I am connecting to my desktop PC and the hub is trying to support many devices all drawing power. As USB C ports typically only supply a low power from the bus, devices seem to be having power issues as they are together all demanding too much from the otherwise unpowered hub so are intermittently connecting, so my question is:

Is it safe to connect this hub to a power source and connect that to the PC which has its own power source?

My feeling is this would be fine, and the standard has considered this. The hub itself should be clever enough to know to ask for power, and the motherboard too should be smart enough to prevent power from coming from the hub, but I would like to be sure before I plug something in and then smell smoke. As a follow up, is there any limit to the power supply you can use, eg, can I use a 65W power supply for a laptop? If it's device dependent, what information should I be looking up, i.e. what's the correct terminology?

Comment: The hub may be incorrectly reporting to be self-powered. You can check this with Device Manager or `lsusb` or whatever. The hub may also not implement USB-PD correctly. You should not have any problems if everything implemented USB correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @DanielB - The hub itself is advertised as having a powered input capable of handling up to 100W. There is also an interface port for connecting to a laptop which carries that power. It is this one:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B08282ZJ19/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I also have a ThinkPad dock which I could also use, specifically this one:

https://www.lenovo.com/gb/en/accessories-and-monitors/docking/universal-cable-docks-usb/TP-USB-C-Dock-Gen2-UK/p/40AS0090UK

Comment: I’m not referring to the paper specs, but rather what the hub electronically reported to the USB host when it was connected.